# Magento 2: How to get Admin Token via Rest API in Postman?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token

Magento 2: I want to get admin token via Rest API. Early I used:

End point
POST  / rest / <store_code> / V1 / integration / admin / token

Headings
Content-Type / json app

Payload
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "123123q"
}

But now this method doesn't work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you share the response you are getting back?

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <title>401 Authorization Required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>401 Authorization Required</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
            <center>nginx</center>
        </body>
    </html>

Answer (score 2):

POST ==> https://example.com/index.php/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token

Header ==> Content-Type  application/json

Body ==> raw   {"username": "name", "password": "password"}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used a similar method. But it doesn't work. I got: "401 Authorization Required." Everything worked fine before.